# Why is tin(IV) iodide bright orange while elemental iodine is violet?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, color, halides

Does it have anything to with iodines polarizability? Is there a way to explain this using sigma bonding or an MO diagram?

Comment: Well, they're completely different compounds. Is there any reason you'd expect them to **not** have different colours?

Comment: Why is $\ce{KI}$ white? As @NicolauSakerNeto said there is no reason why they should have the same colour, simply because they contain a common element.

Comment: I understand that. I was hoping someone could explain in terms of MO theory or bonding symmetry. For example, is the I-I bond much lower energy than the Sn-I bond so it would absorb more lower frequencies of light?